# Sharing data between AngularJS controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

How do I store the items I've selected in a checkbox with other controllers?

My attempt (see [**the plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/anlPsOcbARhB4T6WtVZq) for views):

#### script.js (controllers)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('CooSelection', function () {
  return {selectedCoo: []}
})

function CooListCtrl($scope, CooSelection) {
  $scope.coos = {"Coos": ["spark", "nark", "hark", "quark"]};

  $scope.coo_list_selection = CooSelection;

  $scope.checkSelection = function (item) {
    if ($scope.coo_list_selection.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      $scope.coo_list_selection.push(item);
    } else {
      $scope.coo_list_selection.splice($scope.coo_list_selection.lastIndexOf(item), 1);
    }
  }
}

CooListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'CooSelection'];

function DebugCooList($scope, CooSelection) {
  $scope.coo_selection = CooSelection;
}

DebugCooList.$inject = ['$scope', 'CooSelection'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you reference the `CooSelection` service, you are expecting an array, but the factory returns an object. You could do this instead:

```
myApp.factory('CooSelection', function () {
    return [];    // Return an array instead of an object.
})
```

Also, in your `DebugCooList` controller, your scope property does not match the name of the variable you are checking in the view.  The controller code assigns to `coo_selection` but the view checks `coo_list_selection`, so you'll need to change one to match the other.